# Dark text color on dark menu

Tags: 11.04, themes

After I rebooted 15 min ago, I noticed that Unity clock and menu text changed to dark for apparently no reason, so I rebooted again in a hope to remedy. Unfortunately still same:

[image]

I launched Appearance dialog, and tried to change themes, then revert to my favourite and very common [Dust theme](https://launchpad.net/dusttheme), but for some reason I still get this dark text.

I remember Update manager did some updates today and I checked the log. I think I found the problem - among updated packages there was also update for "Light Themes (Ambiance and Radiance)" with this change log:

> light-themes (0.1.8.13.1) natty-proposed; urgency=low
>
> [Andrea Cimitan]   * Don't load gedit.rc custom settings, as they
>   are introducing
>       regressions (LP: #740864)
>
> -- Paul Sladen   Fri, 29 Apr 2011 15:11:15 +0200

How to solve this problem?
Should I downgrade this package or there is better solution?

Update: Strangely downgrading `light-themes` package didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time but I find out what was it. At least I think it is as I'll explain, if maybe someone is in similar scenario.

AFAIK, Dust themes does not work well with Ubuntu global menu panel, if selected theme uses dark menus. When I first installed Dust theme I included gnome panel resource from Ambiance in Dust's gtkrc file as last line:

```
include "../../Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/gnome-panel.rc"
```

and added one more line inside `gnome-panel.rc`:

```
text[NORMAL]    = shade (0.9, @selected_fg_color)
```

at line 12, as a workaround.

That was some time ago so I totally forgot about it.

Now when Update Manger updated `light-theme` packages, `gnome-panel.rc` got overwritten.

That was the issue